# Ajax request is not giving any data

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am following a tutorial and making a single page app using laravel and vue.js. But at a certain point, an ajax request is not giving me the expected output. I have been trying many ways but nothing is working.

## template I'm facing problem with

```
<template>
    <v-container>
        <v-form @submit.prevent="create">
            <v-autocomplete
                    :items="categories"
                    item-text="name"
                    item-value="id"
                    v-model="form.category_id"
                    label="Category"
            ></v-autocomplete>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                form: {
                    title: null,
                    category_id: null,
                    body: null
                },
                categories: {}, //Expecting to populate the object with axios request.
                errors: {}
            };
        },
        created() {
            axios.get("/api/category").then(res => (this.categories = res.data.data)); //This line is not populating the 'categories' object.
        },
    };
</script>
```

## Category controller where I'm sending axios request

```
class CategoryController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return Category::latest()->get();
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $category = new Category();
        $category->name = $request->name;
        $category->slug = Str::slug($request->name);
        $category->save();
        return response('Created',Response::HTTP_CREATED);
    }

    public function show(Category $category)
    {
        return $category;
    }

    public function update(Request $request, Category $category)
    {
        $category->update(['name'=>$request->name,'slug'=>Str::slug($request->name)]);
    }

    public function destroy(Category $category)
    {
        $category->delete();
        return response(null,Response::HTTP_NO_CONTENT);
    }
}
```

I expect to get the categories object to be populated with the axios request, but the categories boject is undefined

Comment: Nothing changed, same result

Comment: Which method in your controller is for `"/api/category"`?

Comment: @YeasirArafatHridoy Any error in Console. check Network (Chrome Inspect) tab and see your request response.

Comment: @RossWilson index() method for "/api/category"

Comment: In that case please see my answer below.

Comment: @AffanMalik I have tried axios.get(http://localhost:8000/api/categories); and it returns Promise with appropriate data

Comment: Thanks @RossWilson, my mistake was to use `res.data.data`.
I had to use `res.data` only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `/api/category` is  for your `index()` method,  the reason you're not getting any results is because you're not returning anything keyed by `data` (the 2nd in `res.data.data`), the information you need will be in `res.data`.

```
created() {
    axios.get("/api/category")
        .then(res => this.categories = res.data)
        .catch(err => console.log(err)); 
},
```